# Windows batch: analogue for `timeout` command

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I'm trying to find out how to limit a program execution time *within* a Windows batch file. Is there something like Unix `timeout` command?
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and use unix-style `timeout` command from the distribution.

Answer (score 4):

To limit the time a program has to run you could do something like this

```
start yourprogram.exe
timeout /t 10
taskkill /im yourprogram.exe /f
```

That starts `yourprogram.exe`, waits 10 seconds, then kills the program.

Comment: That's not what Im' looking for. Unix `timeout` command allows to limit execution time of a program/script/command.

Comment: Ah right, sorry, I have never used Unix before. I have updated my answer, which will hopefully answer your question.

Comment: Actually the program execution can take from 10min to 3-4hours. I'd like to limit this time to 2 hours. So when the app finishes in 10 mins I don't want the batch job to wait 1hr 50 mins. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could implement that with batch, unless there was something to check for that program did after it was finished, which the batch could pick up and then end early. Unless you wrote the app in question I can't think of any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a timeout command. However, you can start executing a task in the background and sleep (using ping) for the timeout duration then kill the task.

Comment: What do you mean by "*using ping*"?

Answer (score 0):

This code waits 60 seconds, then checks to see if %ProgramName% is running.

To increase this time, change the value of `WaitForMinutes`.

To decrease the interval between checks, set `WaitForSeconds` for the number of seconds you want it to wait.

```
@echo off
set ProgramName=calc.exe
set EndInHours=2

:: How Many Minutes in between each check to see if %ProgramName% is Running
:: To change it to seconds, just set %WaitForSeconds% Manually
set WaitForMinutes=1
set /a WaitForSeconds=%WaitForMinutes%*60

:: How many times to loop
set /a MaxLoop=(%EndInHours%*60*60) / (%WaitForMinutes%*60)

REM Use a VBScript popup window asking to terminate %ProgramName%
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo Wscript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "Click 'OK' to terminate %ProgramName%." ,10 ,"Terminate %ProgramName%", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs

start %ProgramName%
set running=True
:: Give time for %ProgramName% to launch.
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%x in (1,1,%MaxLoop%) do (
  if "!running!"=="True" for /l %%y in (1,1,%WaitForMinutes%) do (
    if "!running!"=="True" (
      set running=False
      REM call Pop-Up
      cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
      if !errorlevel!==-1 (
        for /f "skip=3" %%x in ('tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME EQ %ProgramName%"') do set running=True
      ) else (
        taskkill /im %ProgramName%
      )
    )
  )
)
if exist %tmp%\tmp.vbs del %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

This code uses VBScript to make a pop-up box. Clicking `OK` will cause %ProgramName% to be killed via `taskkill`.

---

If you do not want to use a pop-up window, you can use `timeout` by removing...

```
REM Use a VBScript popup window asking to terminate %ProgramName%
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > %tmp%\tmp.vbs
echo Wscript.Quit (WshShell.Popup( "Click 'OK' to terminate %ProgramName%." ,10 ,"Terminate %ProgramName%", 0)) >> %tmp%\tmp.vbs
```

...and replacing this...

```
      REM call Pop-Up
      cscript /nologo %tmp%\tmp.vbs
      if !errorlevel!==-1 (
```

...with this:

```
      REM Use CTRL+C to kill %ProgramName%
      timeout /t %WaitForSeconds% /nobreak
      if !errorlevel!==0 (
```

Using `/nobreak` is necessary because `timeout` does not distinguish between pressing a key or timing out.  This will allow you to terminate %ProgramName% by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+C , but that causes your batch file to ask `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` when you do. Sloppy/Messy/Nasty IMHO.

---

You could instead use `CHOICE` by replacing the above mentioned code with this:

```
      REM Using choice, but choice can get stuck with a wrong keystroke
      Echo [K]ill %ProgramName% or [S]imulate %WaitForSeconds% Seconds
      Choice /n /c sk /t %WaitForSeconds% /d s
      if !errorlevel!==1 (
```

But choice brings it's own set of limitations to the table. For one thing, it will stop it's countdown if a key that is not among it's choices (in this case `s` and `k`) has been pressed, essentially locking up until a correct choice is made. Second, the <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> cannot be a choice.

Comment: What if I start several instances with the different start and execution times?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use the BusyBox for Windows (https://frippery.org/busybox/ https://github.com/rmyorston/busybox-w32) with the command `busybox timeout 10 yourprogram.exe`.