# How to timeout a command in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a command sleep after some seconds.

For example: `tree & timeout /t 1`

Then it would only show the top of the folders.

I have tried:

```
@echo off
Cd c:\Windows
Tree & timeout /t 1
Echo !
Pause >nul
```

and

```
Cd c:\Windows
Tree & ping 1.1.1.1. -n 1 -w 1000 >nul
Echo !
Pause >nul
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will not be possible using only a single batch file. The commands are run *in order*, from top to bottom, just as if you'd typed them into the command prompt yourself. So you'd need a second batch file that could kill the process launched by the first. That starts getting ugly, maybe it's time to look for alternative solutions...

Comment: I am just guessing here, though. Someone *might* know a way, that's why I just posted a comment instead of an answer. I'm just saying not to hold your breath. :-)

Comment: So is it possible to take out / break(c^) one command in a batch without writing millions of codes, reprogramming the os and win a price for doing all this? (*lol*)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch: analogue for \`timeout\` command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394338/windows-batch-analogue-for-timeout-command)

Comment: (Hade typing on iphone, they get so confused by return button and add comment button, lol xD)

Comment: Just because you put 2 commands in one line with an ampersand between them doesn't mean they're run in parallel. The ampersand is for daisy-chaining commands. The 2nd command will start only after the first one finishes.

Comment: Maybe the selection would be to make a mulit command like opening programs through programs? (Witch i have tried)

Comment: Example tree > timeout /t 1.                        Like start hallo.txt > notepad.exe > explorer.exe

Comment: Idk, but when i find out how i'll let you know ;-).           Regards J

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate of an already existing similar question. I suggest you take an actual look at the answers to that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a `LMC`* in the Windows command shell window.

* <sub>*Left Mouse Click*</sub>

Comment: Can u add friends on this page? :-)

Comment: @JonathanAgerskov No. SO is a Q&A site, not a social network.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this might be (I have some doubts...) but some user put their friends at the profile site, eg. [pattyd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2400000/pattyd).

Comment: [Resolving](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106717) [all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/886) [doubt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65261).

Comment: @Ansgar thanks. Best answer 'We are all friends here... Why would we need a friend list?' Lol.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8243

Comment: No dough, but It could be fooooog awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This will show a page at a time, if that is what you need:

```
tree | more
```