# How can I limit the duration of a Bat file execution

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a `.bat` file that look like this:

```
start <program1>
start <program2>
pause
```

And that makes the job for opening the two programs I want at once.

But what should I do if, for instance, I want them to stop running after 1 hour?

Comment: Maybe [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20834903/2861476) works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look, it seems like what I want...