# Terminate program if execution time is longer in command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I write the code as following in batch file

```
@echo off
cd c:\temp
set st = %TIME%
loop
set et = %TIME%
if %st% - %et% > 1000(taskkill /f /im loop.exe)
```

but in this code, if program loop (loop.exe) loops forever, command after loop command never will be reached. What can I do? Please help!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20834903/2861476) can help

Comment: OMG, thanks. You saved my life <3 so much :)