# Taskkill and timer in batch

Tags: batch-file, timer, taskkill

I currently have this batch script:

```
start udp%1.exe
timeout /t %2
taskkill /f /im "udp%1.exe"
```

This works great and kills the program after a selected amount of time, however if I was to manually close udp%1.exe and start another one with the same ID the timer from the other batch script is still running and will kill the next launched. I'm not entirely sure if I can check if the process is still running in batch? and if so to close the timer so it doesn't kill others with the same ID?

Comment: Maybe, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20834903/2861476) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@echo off
start "udp%1.exe"
timeout /t %2

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq udp%1.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "udp%1.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto yes
goto no

:yes
taskkill /f /im "udp%1.exe"
exit

:no
exit
```

It waits the selected amount of time and if the program is running, it closes it, and if the program is not running, it exits. If you wan't to detect if the program is closed while the timer is still running, you might want to look into vbs scripts. :)