# Cmd batch: Run an exe but kill if after a period of time, if doesn't resolve

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, kill

I used google but it seems it didin't returned me any relevant links.
Same goes for the reommendations here, so I think I have to ask this as a new question.

Can I run an exe command, but with a timeout included?
Example:

Run the exe, if it does not end alone within 5 minutes, kill it.
The 5 minutes limit is an example, I might want to set it up to 48 hours or something.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. Please add the code you are trying to make work into the question. Until then, enjoy reading about how SO works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20813241/2861476) could help

Comment: MC ND thank you very much. Please turn this to an answer so I can accept it.
As for adding code, what should I had added ?
 Ok here:

C:\somefolder\a.exe param1 param2 param3

I want a command like this to time out after 5 minutes. I was actually looking for an approach like MC ND's suggestion.